# When should I use old( key, value) on blade template ? Is it necessary in latest laravel version?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I noticed that in the older laravel blade template it was recommended to use old (key, value) to retrieve old values when form validation fails. (controller method handling the validation will post back to the form with the as-is data in request object)

Is it still necessary to use it in the latest laravel version ? 
When should one use the old (key, value) function on the form fields on laravel blade template?

Comment: As per `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input` it is still relevant to the latest version, used for returning the request data from a prior submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel there is a convention that most "get me some value" like functions provide a way to cover case "there is no value to get", therefore signature of most *getter* like functions looks like:

```
get('key', $default = null)
```

So in your case you would want to use `old('key', default)` in:

- **create form** when you as programmer set valid default value (not placeholder), perhaps date of some action for "today/now" `old('publish_at', Carbon::now())`.
- **edit form** `old('publish_at', $post->publish_at)`, which means that on first load of edit form input field is pre-populated with data from database